# Show months first weekday with Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get Haskell to output/print months first weekday.
I came up with following code:

```
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Time.Calendar.WeekDate
import Data.Char
day=["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]
year=2017
month=5

weekday = day!!(digitToInt(last(showWeekDate (fromGregorian year month 01)))
```

How do I get Haskell to print weekday, when I run code?
I think there is still some problems with last line of code also.

Comment: What error do you get ? Or is this about printing to standard out

Comment: It's about printing to standard out

Comment: so what does my current answer lack - that you cannot print it to stdout?

Answer (score 1):

### Why not use `Data.Time.Format`?

```
import Data.Time.Format

weekDay = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%a"
```

Should do the trick. I am on the bus so this code is untested.

### Edit

Tested it ✔

If this is an issue about printing to stdout, then you have to call this function either in ghci

```
ghci> let d = fromGregorian 2017 03 08
ghci> let weekday = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%a"
ghci> weekday d
"Wed"
```

or have a main function

```
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Format

main :: IO ()
main = print $ weekday d

d = fromGregorian 2017 03 08
weekday = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%a"
```

then you can `runhaskell` or compile and run and get

```
Wed
```